# Can't open ms access MDB file

Tags: database, ms-access

We have a corrupted .mdb file that contains an important data, We don't know what the problem exactly is. Here are some of the error messages:

1) The form name "خلفية" is misspelled or refers to a form that doesn't exist.

2) Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysAccessObjects'

3)  Access was unable to locate the macro or VBA function. If you are trying to call a macro, make sure that the name of the macro and the name of the macro group are spelled correctly.

We tried several solutions like importing the the corrupted database to a new access file but when we try importing the database it says that there is no permission to import the tables and queries.

Comment: Is the previous backup copy corrupted also?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Access database, then on the 'External Data' tab select Access and import everthing from your old database, Tables, Forms, Queries, Modules etc.

When done, [compact & repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-database-files-f20401f5-d39d-414c-bfbd-def1bc707324) the database and test.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it says that there is no permission to import the tables and queries.